# Display an ID based with multiple category ID with loop in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, foreach

I'm sorry about the title, but I don't know how to explain it on Title.
So, here's my case.

I Had a table

| id | category | subcategory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Apple |
| 2 | 1 | Orange |
| 3 | 2 | Car |
| 4 | 2 | Motorcycle |

What I want to do is, doing some loop and the output is like this in PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const subkategoris = {
            "1":[
                {value:1,desc:"Apple"},
                {value:2,desc:"Orange"},
                ],
            "2":[
                {value:3,desc:"Car"},
                {value:4,desc:"Motorcycle"},
                ],
...etc
</script>
```

I already trying to loop it but, what I got is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const subkategoris = {
            "1":[
                {value:1,desc:"Apple"},
                ],
            "1":[
                {value:2,desc:"Orange"},
                ],
            "2":[
                {value:3,desc:"Car"},
                ],
            "2":[
                {value:4,desc:"Motorcycle"},
...etc
</script>
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Is that an SQL table? Is the select request executed with PHP?

Comment: Yes, it was an SQL Table, and what i want to do is looping it with diferent table with PHP, and the output is described above.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to achieve and in what language.
You're asking for PHP solution but all the code in JS.

Here it is a JS solution of what I understand you're trying to do

```js
const initialData = [
{
  id: 1,
  category: 1,
  subCategory: 'Apple'
},{
  id: 2,
  category: 1,
  subCategory: 'Orange'
},{
  id: 3,
  category: 2,
  subCategory: 'Car'
},{
  id: 4,
  category: 2,
  subCategory: 'Motorcycle'
},

]

const groupedByCategory = initialData.reduce((res, {id, category, subCategory}) => {
  const existing = res[category] || []
  return {
    ...res,
    [category] : [...existing, {value: id, desc: subCategory}]
  }
}, {});
console.log(groupedByCategory)
```

You can do the same in PHP using array_reduce

```
$data = [...]; // array with the same payload of the js 

$result = array_reduce($data, function($res, $item){
  $category = $item['category'];
  $existing = $res[$category] ?? [];
  $existing[] = ['value' => $item['id'], 'desc' => $item['subCategory']];
  $res[$category] = $existing;
  return $res; 

}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you, the output from the console are what i looking for. But how to display it on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to get your data from an SQL DB with PHP, your request can do the job without needing to loop anything with PHP or JS.

Can you try something like this?

```
$select = $conn->prepare(
    "SELECT
    DISTINCT category,
    id AS subkategoris_value,
    subcategory AS subkategoris_desc
    FROM sometable"
);
$select->execute([]);
$result = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

Here, replace *sometable* with the name of your table and *$conn* with your connection to MySQL DB.

Your output will be directly as expected.